# Numpy dtype 'h' as dtype

Tags: python, numpy

What does the 'h' dtype mean for the argument dtype?
Was not able to find information on it on the numpy docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.uint8

```
data = numpy.memmap("test.pcm", dtype='h', mode='r')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the numpy docs can be hard to navigate. [Here's the main page on dtype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), but it doesn't mention `'h'`.

So to probe it experimentally:

```py
import numpy as np
np.dtype('h')
```

--> `dtype('int16')`

It's a 16-bit signed integer.